# Possible to set UIButton image to be at zero index?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subclass, cashapelayer

I have created a subclass for UIButton where I am drawing a CAShapelayer to serve as circular background color for the button, which works just fine. However that CAShapeLayer is now covering the button image.

What's the best way to handle this? I have tried inserting the CAShapeLayer but that didn't have any effect. Is there a way to bring the button image to the foreground?

This is how I am currently casting the button image:

```
var buttonImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "icon_check")! {
    didSet {
        setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Update: the code for the entire class:

```
class PulseButton: UIButton {

let buttonFillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let pulsatingLayer = CAShapeLayer()

var buttonFillLayerFillColor:   UIColor = .buttonLayerFillColor                                               { didSet { buttonFillLayer.fillColor = buttonFillLayerFillColor.cgColor } }
var pulsatingLayerFillColor:   UIColor = .pulsatingLayerFillColor                                             { didSet { pulsatingLayer.fillColor = pulsatingLayerFillColor.cgColor } }

var buttonFillLayerStrokeStart: CGFloat = 0                                                                   { didSet { buttonFillLayer.strokeStart = buttonFillLayerStrokeStart } }
var pulsatingLayerStrokeStart: CGFloat = 0                                                                    { didSet { pulsatingLayer.strokeStart = pulsatingLayerStrokeStart } }

var buttonFillLayerStrokeEnd:   CGFloat = 1                                                                   { didSet { buttonFillLayer.strokeEnd = buttonFillLayerStrokeEnd } }
var pulsatingLayerStrokeEnd:   CGFloat = 1                                                                    { didSet { pulsatingLayer.strokeEnd = pulsatingLayerStrokeEnd } }

var buttonImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "icon_check")! {
    didSet {
        setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupLayout()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupLayout()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    updatePaths()
}

private func setupLayout() {
    pulsatingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    pulsatingLayer.fillColor = buttonFillLayerFillColor.cgColor
    pulsatingLayer.strokeStart = buttonFillLayerStrokeStart
    pulsatingLayer.strokeEnd  = buttonFillLayerStrokeEnd

    buttonFillLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    buttonFillLayer.fillColor = pulsatingLayerFillColor.cgColor
    buttonFillLayer.strokeStart = pulsatingLayerStrokeStart
    buttonFillLayer.strokeEnd  = pulsatingLayerStrokeEnd

    layer.addSublayer(pulsatingLayer)
    layer.addSublayer(buttonFillLayer)
}

private func updatePaths()  {
    print("Updating")

    //Parameters for layers
    let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
    let radius = (min(bounds.width, bounds.height)) / 2
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true).cgPath

    pulsatingLayer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    pulsatingLayer.frame = bounds
    pulsatingLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi/2, 0, 0, 1)
    buttonFillLayer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    buttonFillLayer.frame = bounds
    buttonFillLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi/2, 0, 0, 1)

    pulsatingLayer.path = path
    buttonFillLayer.path = path
}

func animateCircle() {
    let scaleUpAimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    scaleUpAimation.fromValue = 1
    scaleUpAimation.toValue = 1.4
    scaleUpAimation.duration = 0.8
    scaleUpAimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    self.pulsatingLayer.add(scaleUpAimation, forKey: "pulsing")


    let opacityAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    opacityAnimation.fromValue = 0.6
    opacityAnimation.toValue = 0
    opacityAnimation.duration = 0.8
    opacityAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    pulsatingLayer.add(opacityAnimation, forKey: "changing opacity")
}
}
```

Comment: Add the code where you adding the layer to button.

Comment: Sure, added the entire class.

Comment: Instead of the line "layer.addSublayer(pulsatingLayer)" I used "        layer.insertSublayer(buttonFillLayer, at: 0)" which had no effect - the buttonImage was still behind the layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You're not actually setting the button's image. You try to by creating a `didSet` observer for `buttonImage`, but that observer doesn't get called at initialization time. It only gets called later if `buttonImage` is reassigned. One way to fix this problem is by setting it to itself in `setupLayout()`, like this:

   ```
   private func setupLayout() {
       buttonImage = { buttonImage }()
   ```

   Note that Swift won't let you assign a property to itself, so I use an anonymous closure to get the current `buttonImage` value.
2. You need to let the button do its normal layout before you add your own layers if you want to be sure that your layers go under its other layers. So do **not** add the layers in `setupLayout`. Wait until `layoutSubviews` to insert the layers:

   ```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
       if pulsatingLayer.superlayer == nil {
           layer.insertSublayer(pulsatingLayer, at: 0)
           layer.insertSublayer(buttonFillLayer, at: 1)
       }
       updatePaths()
   }
   ```

Result:

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple sample to add `CAShapeLayer` and UIImage to UIButton.

**1. Extension of `UIButton`**

```
extension UIButton
{
    func addLayer()
    {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

**2. Adding `CAShapeLayer` to `UIButton`**

Add the `CAShapeLayer` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var layerAdded = false

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "furnish_exhaust"), for: .normal)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        if !self.layerAdded
        {
            self.layerAdded = true
            self.button.addLayer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha, also a great solution. Much appreciated!!